# How get value of tag <p:menu> in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am doing a web aplication where I have a menu with a list entities and this entities will be evaluated all it is in a facelets template and I now I need to get the ID of this entity to can evaluate How it do ?

I thought it:

```
<p:menu model="#{entidadView.menuModel}" toggleable="true"   >

     <p:ajax listener="#{grupoView.storeEntidad}"/>

</p:menu>
```

and My bean it is:

```
public MenuModel getMenuModel(){
DefaultSubMenu subMenu2 = new DefaultSubMenu("Auditoria");
    for (Entidad entidad : getAllEntidad() ){
        item = new DefaultMenuItem(entidad.getNombre());
        item.setOutcome("/auditar.xhtml");    
        subMenu2.addElement(item);
    }

    model.addElement(subMenu2);

 //Event to Ajax
public void  storeEntidad(ValueChangeEvent evento){

    this.idEntidad = evento.getNewValue().toString();;
    System.out.println(idEntidad);

 }
```

but say me this error:

```
 <p:ajax> Unable to attach behavior to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

Comment: Just add an actionListener/command to each menu item you create in the model and make sure it uses ajax. See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml. And in the actionListener you can retrieve the event and from that retrieve the relevant information. (sorry, no time to create a full example with an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I did it only send the parameter by the URL of my web pages and I capture it then. 
 My bean:

```
public MenuModel getMenuModel(){
   DefaultSubMenu subMenu2 = new DefaultSubMenu("Auditoria");
    for (Entidad entidad : getAllEntidad() ){
       idEntidad = String.valueOf(entidad.getEntidad_id());
        item = new DefaultMenuItem(entidad.getNombre());
        item.setParam("entidad", idEntidad);
        item.setOutcome("/auditar.xhtml");    
       subMenu2.addElement(item);
}

model.addElement(subMenu2);
}
```

And the next Pages I capture so:

```
<html ...>
  <f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="entidad" value="#{grupoView.idEntidad}"/>
  </f:metadata>

<body>
```

And finaally It was okay !!! (Y)